# Rails logger messages not showing in development log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My development log seems to be working fine (it shows each asset that's loaded etc.) but it won't show any messages I put in code. I have:

```
   Rails.logger.debug "My debugging message"
```

in a method of my controller. The method is called but the message does not show in the development log. This seems pretty basic and I can't see where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I guess in your controller presumably may have the following:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    logger.debug "New user: #{@user.attributes.inspect}"
    logger.debug "User should be valid: #{@user.valid?}"

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
      logger.debug "The User was saved and now the user is going to be redirected..."
      redirect_to(@user)
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Also another technique you may want to add into your `config/environment/development.rb` is:

```
  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  config.log_level = :debug
```

As it states in the comment it will log everything at the debug level.

Further to this some may agree some may disagree something that I am have come across and am learning is to use the ruby debug (`gem install debug)`. With this it allows you put a breakpoint in your code and inspect all local variables at that point and time of execution. You may find it much better to use this technique in tracking bugs that you don't where they are! So you could do something like this.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def new
    debugger
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    .....
     ....
       ..
   end
```

Then when you start the server ensure you run `rails server debugger` further reading: [Guide Ruby On Rails 3.2 - The Shell](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-shell)

Hopefully this clarifies a few things.